# Spyder Program Complete Crash?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

(Edit: Picture of error I see: [Picture of Error Code I see On Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFQu1.jpg)) I don't know what has happened to my Spyder program. I ran a particular program and it gave me a few warnings of "Warning: Large Data might not all display" or something of the sort. I ran an array with 100,000 data points for four separate arrays, but then I logged out when Spyder stopped working. I couldn't even close out of it. But then I restarted my machine and then I keep getting the same error of "Spyder crashed during last session. If Spyder does not start at all *before submitting a bug report*, please try to reset settings to default by running Spyder with the command line option '--reset': spyder -- reset ....." I have tried uninstalling and then reinstalling Spyder, but that has only led to the exact same prompt. And I tried putting the spyder -- rest command into the Anaconda Prompt command window, and I keep getting the same message.

I'm at a complete lost of what I need to do now. I can't open the GUI for the programming at all. I keep getting the same Spyder Crashed prompt over and over again. What should I try now? I have a Latitude E6530 Laptop installed with Windows 10.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "Anaconda Prompt command window", but the suggestion from Spyder means to run it directly from a command line terminal (on Unix) or command prompt (Windows). Is that what you did for the `spyder --reset` command?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Now every time I try reopening Spyder I get the same prompt. But I don't know how to get out of that cycle. I've tried that command over, but I keep getting the same prompt and not being able to even remotely access Spyder.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Why:

As the warning says: **"Large Data might not all display"**, you are trying to run an array that has 100,000 data points. That puts pressure on your machine, and spyder is trying to handle such a big array. It starts taking high amounts of memory and then, spyder crashes.